# Approximate a large number with perfect powers

Tags: number-theory, perfect-powers

I'm dealing with number theory now and I have an interesting question. 
Every number can be approximated with two perfect powers, where perfect power is a number in form $$a^b$$$$a,b \geq 2, a,b \in \mathbb N $$

My question is, how close can I approximate a given number? The number is huge.... So what can be smallest interval which contains the given number and its bounds are perfect powers?

Thank you!

Comment: As you are talking about number theory, am I correct to say that $a,b$ must be integers?

Comment: Yes, of course, I forgot to mention!

Comment: I can approximate the number, but I'm not sure, that I get the closest perfect powers.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? You say that you can approximate the number, it is helpful to include this in your question.

Comment: As far as I know, it might be the case that infinitely many times the gap between two perfect powers is 2, which would give very tight bound. At the same time, we can show that gaps between perfect powers can be as large as we like. Does that answer your question at least partially?

Comment: I tried the following:
I know, how many digit have the large number, so call the g now. 
Then one lower limit can be 10^(d-1). And I generated numbers, that are close to this number. I used the log function to calculate the exponent to any given base. 

Yes, Wojuwo, that makes me calm, sounds this news very well for me.

Comment: Every perfect power is a perfect power with a prime exponent. If you search a small interval, I would start with $[\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2, \lfloor\sqrt{n}+1\rfloor^2]$, and then check if/which third, fifth, seventh, eleventh, ... powers lie in that interval. Finding such a power gives you a smaller interval. I would expect that it is relatively rare that you can do much better than the square-bounded interval, however.

Comment: I don't know yet, but I will give it a try!

But of course I don't want to use the same base, or exponent for upper and lower limit. So they can be:
a^b<=n<=c^d and c^d-a^b is minimal.

Comment: Well, you can approximate every integer greater than or equal to 4 to within a factor of 2 just by powers of 2. I guess the question is if you can get a better factor than "2."

Comment: If you want to know the actual size, suppose for example you just consider powers of 2 and 3 ($2^m$ and $3^m$). Then within $\{1, \ldots, k\}$ there are at most $\log(k)/\log(2) + \log(k)/\log(3)$ such powers, and so there must be intervals with no such powers that have size at least $k/[\log(k)/\log(2) + \log(k)/\log(3)]$, which can get arbitrarily large with $k$.

Comment: Yes, that's why I would like to use different bases and exponents.

Comment: What is the approximate magnitude of the number(s) you want to approximate ? Larger than $10^{10^{10}}$ ?